# Как правильно сделать проверку if else?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Подскажите как правильно сделать проверку на введенный текст пользователем. Мне нужно если текст введённый пользователем содержит меньше 15 символов, и содержит цифры или символы по типу (%№:?;%). То такой текст не принимается, и бот ожидает корректный ввод.
В моем коде что ниже, проверка проходит но только до 15 символов, если больше то проверка не работает в принципе. И если вписать цифры в виде 15 символов, то пропускает такой код. И я не знаю как реализовать проверку ещё на символы. Если кто знает как это реализовать, напишите пожалуйста, буду благодарен за помощь!

```
@dp.message_handler(state=registration_of_the_application.fuul_name)
async def fuul_name_full_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if len(message.text) < 15:
        
        if message.text.isalpha():
            
            await message.answer(text='ФИО СЛИШКОМ КОРОТКОЕ') 
        
        else: 

            await message.answer(text='ФИО НЕ МОЖЕТ ИМЕТЬ ЦИФР')
    else:
        await state.update_data(fuul_name=message.text)
        data_name = message.text

        await message.answer(f'{data_name} подтвердите свой номер!', reply_markup=contact_button)
        await registration_of_the_application.number_contact.set()
```

Comment: самое простое `if len(t) < 15 or not all(x.isalpha() for x in t.split()): print('bad')`

Comment: В первом if выводите просто сообщение, что ФИО слишком короткое, без дополнительных if внутри. Добавляете `elif not message.text.isalpha(): await message.answer(text='ФИО НЕ МОЖЕТ ИМЕТЬ ЦИФР')`. Вообще, правильнее проверять `any(c.isdigit() for c in message.text)` а не `not message.text.isalpha()`

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @insolor спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @splash58 но данная проверка работает только до 15 символов, а если вести после 15 символа цифру или символ, то текст пропускает дальше, как можно поменять сделать проверку на всю строку?

Comment: https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-jlUI9L - сделайте неправильные данные, которые пропускаются

Comment: @splash58 извините за мою тупость, но я ничего не понял с вашего примера по codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-jlUI9L

Comment: что вы не поняли, если оно отрабатывает правильно на ваших тестовых данных, то вместо bad ругайтесь, что неправильные данные введены, а вместо ок - считайте, что они похожи на правильные, и делайте, что вы там хотите с ними делать